# React Skin built on Microsoft CRM - integration with outlook

Tags: reactjs, dynamics-crm, outlook-2010

We are building a product and UI in react on Dynamics CRM. We want to know can we integrate our task creation feature with outlook.

Also want to know if we can read images of outlook and have it in UI.

Can we also read leave, out of office notification and put a rule to not assign tasks during those period.

Thanks
Shraddha

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
Please describe your question in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual task you want to accomplish, add you erroneous code snippet and what all resolutions you actually tried already to eradicate the issue.
Make note to add corresponding tags and format your code before pasting here.
For more details, visit StackOverflow's guidelines including https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) and [Graph react tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/graph/tutorials/react), but I'm not sure whether it can access leave, out of office notification or not, you should find out from the official docs